# Write a loop that looks for the largest element in the matrix

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matrix

Write a loop that looks for the largest element in the matrix

Matrix example:

```
test_matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
[7, -1, 2],
[123, 2, -1]]
```

All my attempts failed to carry out this task( I expect to solve this problem and command "print" will show right answer

Comment: _All my attempts failed_ Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flatten the matrix and use the builtin `max`.

```py
test_matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
               [7, -1, 2],
               [123, 2, -1]]

largest = max(i for sublist in test_matrix for i in sublist)
print(largest)
```

Comment: This one works appropiately, thanks!